# using System.Web.Caching; giving error

Tags: .net, reference, console-application

(i am creating console application)
i can't see System.web dll under "add references"  the .NET framework 4
client profile.

> WCF project, system is giving error when i am specifying:
>   using System.Web.Caching;
>    it is not recognizing the above namespace.
>
> that's why:
>   this.Context.Cache,
>   this.Context.Cache.Add,
>   cacheHolder,
>
> are not working.

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much answered your own question: using the client profile, `System.Web.dll` doesn't exist. You'll either need the full profile, or remove all references to types in `System.Web.Caching` and any other types in `System.Web.dll`.